# .Net Framework Compatible Unexpected Error?

Tags: .net, frameworks

I am constanly receiving this error on my VAIO Laptop every time I start it.
I am looking for solution to this since long.

```
Model No: VPCEB46FG (Windows 7 Premium 64 bit)
.Net Framework Compatible Error:
Unhandled exception has occurred in your application

Exception Text
`
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)

at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)

at VCsystray.AccFunctions.nextSilentRun()

at VCsystray.Form1.CheckOneClickLastRun()

at VCsystray.Form1.tmrOneclick_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)

at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)

at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)

at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
`
```

I already have the updated .net framework and other updates of Windows 7 and VAIO softwares still I am facing the same plroblem.

Any of your suggestions are welcome.
Please do assist the best.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Quick Google shows that the program that is crashing is called "VAIO Care". My best guess is that your Windows locale is not set to English, and that's why the program is failing to parse the current date. Try switching your settings to English, rebooting, to see if this problem disappears. If it is, I suggest you report this bug to Sony VAIO somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following links can help you:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/unhandled-exception-has-occurred-in-your/773c9154-1919-4fdf-ac8d-4bc8432ea871

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to `Convert.ToDateTime` which, according to your current system settings, does not represent a valid `DateTime`.

For example, passing "Today is Monday, the 9th of March" to `Convert.ToDateTime` will bring up this exception, as .NET doesn't know how to make a `DateTime` from this string.

This is not a .NET problem, but an error in the application passing a string in the wrong format.

**EDIT**
It seems to be an error in an application that is started automatically when you log in. If you did not write this application yourself, the problem can only be solved by the software vendor. Most probably they assume the application to run on US-locale systems, but you're running on a different locale.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with whatever VCsystray is. I am guessing it is parsing a date from a string but localisation issues are preventing it from recognising the date format. Find this software and update it or get rid of it. Or possibly change the locale of your computer but I am guessing that is not a practical response.